# malformed entry help

Tags: command-line, apt, 21.04

I am having an issue using terminal. After installing wine I keep getting an error stating Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_hirsute-hirsute.list (Component)

Comment: The error message tells you the line which contains the error, plus the file that contains the error. We cannot see what is in that file so cannot help you there.  (the directory it's located in is empty on a clean install; so the entry was added by someone with `sudo` rights)

Comment: 1 deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/hirsute main
2 deb-src https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/hirsute main

Comment: Im guessing there should be a space between "/" and "hirsute"

Comment: Yes there should be .. the *hirsute* is your release which is a separate field, where the space(s) are the delimiters for those fields.

Comment: OK. so then I should use sudoedit to change that?

Comment: You can use whatever editor/tool you used to create it.. Myself I'd use `vim` which is **not** a newbie-friendly editor so it'd be something you likely should avoid.

Comment: Awesome thank you. i followed the advice from the link you posted. $ sudo -H gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_hirsute-hirsute.list brought up text editor where i added the space. issue resolved